# Including stylesheets from header.php with a relative path

Tags: relative-path, php-include

i am working on a website and i am looking for a way to include all my stylesheets and scripts relatively. Including the php-files is easy:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

or

```
<?php include '../header.php'; ?>
```

or by referencing the root-path:

```
<?php include '/header.php'; ?>
```

But: All the stylesheets and scripts are not loaded on pages located in ‘/products‘, because they are located relatively to the root-directory and not to root/products.

For example:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way to include stylesheets and scripts relativlely, without taking care of where the page is located, that is calling header.php?

I am working on a local server with mamp and there are many websites in the mamp-directory.

Thanks in advance!

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the HTML. The following will load a stylesheet relative to the page you are currently on.

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

For example, if your page is /products/page1.html. The browser will try to load /products/css/styles.css

An absolute path would look like:

```
 <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note the additional forward slash.  In this case although your page is /products/page1.html. The browser will try to load /css/styles.css

You can also use the base tag to change the relative urls as in the first example.

```
<base href="/assets/" />
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This time the browser will try to load /assets/css/styles.css

Comment: Thank you, Steve! 

Unfortunately it does not work properly. What do i do wrong?

 `<base href="http://localhost/planilux/02/" />
  
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
    <link href="/css/hacks.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Take the forwardslash out in front of your css paths. /css/bootstrap.min.js should be css/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've found the solution:

The base-function tells my website to be based in     `http://localhost/planilux/02/`

```
<base href="http://localhost/planilux/02/" />
```

I've been trying to get my stylesheet by telling the path to be root-based:

```
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The little slash before `css`in the path was the problem.

This works out fine:

```
<link href="css/hacks.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks !!! Have a nice day!